# Raspberry Pi - Line Scan like image

Tags: raspicam, image

i got involved in a small hobbyist project in which a small ball has to be detected through a small gap. Accordingly there are only a view "lines" of a picture usable to find the vector "through" the ball.

After a view calculations the minimum horizontal resolution is about 1920 pixels at a frame-rate of 70+FPS. Every of the installed cameras will be set up with an individual pi.

So far so good. I am pretty inexperienced when it comes to cameras and i have these two resulting questions i could not find a solution for:

1. Is it possible to take only line wise shots with the CSI-2 protocol and to raise the frame-rate accordingly? -> if this is possible i could use the basic Rpi V2 camera.
2. When this is not possible...do you know a manufacturer for affordable line scan cameras that will match my requirements?

If you have another idea feel free to brainstorm. 
Thank yo very much.

Comment: I can't see that the Pi is relevant to this question.  The CSI-2 protocol is surely published.  Asking for camera suggestions will be off topic.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Note that we are not a discussion style forum and open ended invitations to brainstorm are not appropriate to the format. Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.